# finding files with names in numeric text

Tags: find

I am trying to find all the files in the current directory  whose names only contains numeric digits  like 111 1101 3348 444. tried

```
find . -name "[0-9]\+" -type f
```

but this does not work   when I run

```
find . -name "[0-9]*" -type f
```

this works , can Some one explain why is first command not finding the numeric file names ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-name` argument only accept an [unix glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

You can't use regex inside of it. Use `-regex` if you need more power, but then you need to fully match the path.